# Winforms: Error in iterating excel rows of same column

Tags: c#, excel

Apologies for somewhat confusing explanation. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Purpose for code below is to

1) Iterate all rows in Column B of excel sheet named oSheet1

2) Iterate all rows in Column 0 of datagridview (DTG)

3) If data from Column B and Column 0 matches, then export data in Column 1 of DTG into Column C of excel.

Hence, the data in column 1 of DTG is in reference with data in Column 0 of DTG. And data in Column C of excel will eventually be in reference with Column B of excel. I've inserted some images for easy understanding[image: DTG] [image]

I've tried multiple codes for hours and kept getting error. Below are my codes along with errors experienced:

**Error: Cannot perform in runtime binding on null reference**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= oSheet1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                string cellvalue = oSheet1.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString(); //error here
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                   if ((string)row.Cells[0].Value == cellvalue)
                    {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        oSheet1.Cells[i, 3] = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Error: Exception from H result**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= oSheet1.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
            object cellvalue = oSheet1.get_Range("B:B" + Convert.ToString(i));
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value == cellvalue)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
                    {
                        oSheet1.Cells[i, 3] = dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!!

Comment: Are you intentionally skipping the first column by starting the `for` loop at `1`? Shouldn't the loop be `for (int i = 0; i < oSheet1.Columns.Count; i++)`?

Comment: Your comment that says `//error here` is when `i` is what value?

Comment: You are doing this `oSheet1.Cells[i, 2]` (`oSheet1.Cells[ROW, COL]`) in that loop : `for (int i = 1; i <= oSheet1.Columns.Count; i++)`. `i` is used as row iterator, but you are comparing it against the col count.

Comment: Hi guys, I get what yall meant. And yeah, I made the change. Thanks for that. But the error still persist in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `UsedRange`.

```
var range = oSheet1.UsedRange;
int startingRowIndex = range.Row + 1; //to skip the header
for (int rowIndex = startingRowIndex; rowIndex < range.Row + range.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    string cellvalue = range.Cells[rowIndex, 2].Value?.ToString();
    ...
}
```

Also, you should perform a null check against the Value property just in case the cell is empty, or uses a [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) as shown in the code above.

Comment: Hi Kenny, made the changes from columns to rows. But the error still persist in the same line. As for the null conditioned operator, it made my application hang so I removed it.

Comment: I will look into this. Could you send me a copy of your excel (or make one that can be used to recreate this issue)? Post it on GitHub and post the link here.

Comment: Hi Kenny. Attached is the link (https://github.com/atisyam/masyita/blob/master/stackoverflow.xlsx). Appreciate your time sir.